# Find the bottom left + upper right corners (latitude, longitude) with Mapbox - [Android]

Tags: java, android, mapbox

Using MapBox in Android, I am trying to find the lower left corner and upper right corner.  I cannot find anywhere in their documentation to retrieve this information.

Comment: Hey Tim could you help me better understand what you mean by find the bottom left + upper right corners? Is it a bounding box you are trying to get? Glad to help if you can give a little more information

Comment: Yeah I am trying to get the bounding box of the map being displayed.  And I would like to retrieve those 2 points' coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>This line of code should accomplish what your trying to do:</s>

`LatLngBounds bounds = mapboxMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;`

**EDIT**

Sorry about that, This is a feature upcoming in 4.0. for now you can use this as a work around:

```
int viewportWidth = mMapView.getWidth();
int viewportHeight = mMapView.getHeight();

LatLng topLeft = mMapView.fromScreenLocation(new PointF(0, 0));
LatLng topRight = mMapView.fromScreenLocation(new PointF(viewportWidth, 0));
LatLng bottomRight = mMapView.fromScreenLocation(new PointF(viewportWidth, viewportHeight));
LatLng bottomLeft = mMapView.fromScreenLocation(new PointF(0, viewportHeight));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Mapbox's mapview does not have the getProjection method.

Comment: Mucho gracias cammace, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Thank you. I was searching forever. I think now, only the first method is relevant anymore.